# Instalar Linux desde un cdrom montado - Red Hat 7

Tags: linux

Tengo acceso por medio de una VPN a un equipo el cual tiene instalado lo basico de linux, no tiene entorno visuales.
Intente instalar KDE y GNOME para poder incorporarle un entorno grafico y al intentar iniiciarlo, me genera un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busque en mucho foros este error y no encontre demasiado, como que es muy generico

Es por esa razón que deseo reinstalar la version de linux.

Tengo el cdrom montado pero no se desde que directorio debo iniciar la instalación, ya que tengo todo como "Descomprimido", no tengo un setup o install como para comenzar.

No puedo cambiarle el boteo, ya que es una VM y no tengo acceso al equipo fisico para cambiar el boot, por esta razón les pido ayuda, para saber a partir de los archivo que muestro abajo y que es el contenido del cdrom, puedo instalar todo nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias,
Osky

Comment: Si estas entrando en otra máquina via SSH, recuerda que para entrar en modo ventanas te hace falta tener encendido un servidor X como VcXsrv, y activar el reenvio X11 en el cliente SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se debe ejecutar el comando startx como root, sólo desde otro usuario. Dependiendo de qué entorno tengas instalado, será más conveniente que utilices kdm (si es kde tu entorno), xdm (si usas xfce), etc., para iniciar el servidor Xorg, y posteriormente te logueas en gráfico con otro usuario. 
Prueba a eliminar el fichero Xauthority del usuario root (estará oculto en su home, dado que cada usuario que accede a Xorg tiene el suyo) , crea un usuario con los permisos básicos (revisa el man useradd), y usa startx con ese usuario.
El fichero Xauthority estará oculto, por lo que estará precedido por un punto (.) y tendrás que listarlo con la opción -a de ls.
Más sobre el fichero Xauthority https://docs.citrix.com/es-es/linux-virtual-delivery-agent/7-12/configuration/configure-xauthority.html